# Need help to extract 'Email Id' using ContactsApp function in 'Google Script'

Tags: google-apps-script

I have written a '**Google script**' to extract the '**Email Address**' using the `ContactsApp.getContactsByName` function. My below mentioned script is working but not giving any output in Column B of 'Google Sheet'.

```
function test2() {
   var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var cell = s.getRange('a1');
for (var x = 1; x <= 15; x++) { 
  var r = s.getRange(x,1);
  var b = r.getValue()
     if(b)
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
  nextCell.setValue(ContactsApp.getContactsByName[b]);
}
}
```

Thereafter, I tried to make these changes in the last line of the code it throws an error message:-

Change 1)

```
  nextCell.setValue(ContactsApp.getContactsByName[b].getEmails());
```

Change 2)

```
nextCell.setValue(ContactsApp.getContactsByName[b].getAddresses());
```

Change 3)

```
nextCell.setValue(ContactsApp.getContactsByName[b].getEmails().getAddresses());
```

How can I write the correct script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getEmails() method will return an array if a contact has any associated email address. You need to call getAddress() on individual array items to get the actual email value.

Simple example here:

```
var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByName("name here");
var email = contacts[0].getEmails()[0].getAddress();
Logger.log(email);
```

Comment: Thanks Amit for help